# How to pin selected UITableView row to top or bottom (so it doesn't go out of view) when scrolling

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am looking to add a feature to a UITableView where a selected row pins to the top or bottom when a user scrolls out of range.

For example, let's say I have 100 cells. The user scrolls down and cell #12 becomes visible, and they select it. As the user continues to scroll down, once cell #12 reaches the top of the table view, I want that cell to be pinned to the top in a fixed position, but the other cells continue to scroll underneath it. If the user ever scrolls back up to the original location of the 12th cell, this cell will then unpin and resume scrolling down the page like normal until it reaches the bottom, in which case it will now pin to the bottom as the user continues to scroll up.

I have scoured the internet and, although it seems to have been questioned by a few different people (such as [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/any-ideas-on-how-to-achieve-this-layout/1581)), I'm not seeing a clear answer as to how this can be achieved.

One way I thought of doing it is potentially detecting when a particular row reaches the top, and when that happens, copy the contents of that cell into a new UIView instance which can act as a replica of the cell; then I can pin this view to the top. However, with this method, I'm still a bit confused on how how I can detect when the row is at the top of the UITableView to know when to show the pinned replica view...

Otherwise, if you guys can think of any other methods to achieve this that would work better, that would be awesome.

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66466497/14351818) recently, maybe check it out

Comment: Ooo perfect, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: So should I delete this question then? Not really sure since I'm sorta new.

Comment: I'll mark it as a duplicate. This way other people can find the similar question too.

Comment: First time marking as duplicate. The above comment was auto generated :D

Comment: Haha first for both of us.